# Model View ViewModel + WPF - need further understanding

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I'm brand new to both MVVM and WPF, and I've been reading, but I don't think I'll find an answer specific enough without clocking significant time so I've come here.

I have a package where I have a ton of XAML files, which are obviously used for the GUI.  When I expand those XAML files, there is a .xaml.cs file.  Also, in the same package, I have *_*__ViewModel.cs files.  My question is, is this where the heart of the system is?

My misunderstanding is--are the .XAML files the View, the .xaml.cs the Model, and the *_*_ViewModel.cs files the ViewModels?  I'm not entirely sure about the .xaml.cs, where as the other two are quite obvious.  If the .xaml.cs files aren't the Model, how do I determine what is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.xaml.cs` files are just the code-behind for the View, and as such, are part of that layer (as the other answer notes).

As you guessed, the `*ViewModel.cs` files compose the various view models. That naming convention is pretty standard.

Defining the **Model** is somewhat tricky, as it changes based on the application. In general, its the "core" of your application, what everything else is *actually* based on.

That can be a database, a web service, a TCP socket connection, and a number of other things. Whats important is that it *in no way relates to the view*. You won't see it in the naming scheme of the files, but its pretty obvious what it is if you look at the design of the program.

Answer (score 1):

*.XAML.cs* files are also part of the view. They are what is referred to as the code behind. If you are using MVVM then generally speaking you will rarely need to access these files, because instead of adding event handlers to the code behind, you will be using Commanding to bind commands to your view model.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you.  How do I determine the Model files though?  Will that be all low-level code in a seperate project?

Comment: or is that moreso left up to the developer? I picked up a one-man project and with poor documentation, I can't determine much.

It looks like there is the main application, a "____Control" package, and a couple "_____Library" packages.  Also an "_____API" package.  I think those are all mostly of my main interest that I will be dealing with.  Sorry I can't show screenshots/examples.

Comment: What constitutes the model (and viewmodel for that matter) would be determined by the developer. In your case the viewmodel files are obvious. The model could be anything, whatever the main business object/data that your application operates on. I would guess that it would be in the main application project somewhere.   Without looking at your code, I would guess that ___Control *could* be controls used in the views, ___Library *could* be some custom or third party libraries used by the application, and ___API *could* define an API for others to code against, but those are just guesses.

Comment: I will determine this as an answer.  Without looking, you got it for the most part right from what I can tell.  To note: the libraries contain mostly interfaces, if that helps potentially describe thier use.